# Issue with substituting a new variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a function of the form 
$$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t}{\frac{u_0\,x\exp[-h\tau-(x^2/4k\tau)]}{2\sqrt{\pi k\tau^3}}}d\tau$$
Now substituting $\eta=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{k\tau}}$ in the above equation, I get (tried five times)

$$u(x,t)=\frac{2u_0}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x/2\sqrt{kt}}^{\infty}{\exp[-\eta^2{\color{red}{-}}(hx^2/4k\eta^2)]}d\eta$$

But in the book `Linear Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers by Tyn Myint-U and Lokenath Debnath, page 470`, they end up with

$$u(x,t)=\frac{2u_0}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x/2\sqrt{kt}}^{\infty}{\exp[-\eta^2{\color{red}{+}}(hx^2/4k\eta^2)]}d\eta$$
I have two questions, how come we are to use that particular substitution and the second one why the different sign? Who is at fault?

Comment: I get the minus sign too : if $\eta=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{k\tau}}$, then $\tau=\frac{x^2}{4k\eta^2}$ so that $-h\tau$ becomes $-\frac{hx^2}{4k\eta^2}$. This substituion can remove the $\tau$ factors outside of the exponential, so we get something like $\exp\left(a\eta^2+b/\eta^2\right)$ to integrate.

Comment: I agree with your own equation. Trust yourself, not the book.

Comment: It is impossible to tell why that substitution was used without knowing what the authors do further with it. In general, substitutions are chosen based upon what direction you want to advance your proof into, i.e. it is the proof strategy that suggests what substitution to chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The substitution is used obtain the final expression in terms of an error function. Notice that they set $h=0$ after this substitution, and in that case $\eta=x/(2\sqrt{k\tau})$ is the square root of the exponent, i.e. $\eta^2=x^2/(4k\tau)$.

2) It looks like a typo in the book